# Option Prices under the Heston Stochastic Volatility Model

Tags: stochastic-volatility

I was wondering if anyone has come across a more straightforward derivation of the semi-closed form solution for the price of a european call under the Heston model than the one proposed by Heston (1993) ?

Comment: can you add link to this paper?

Comment: http://www.javaquant.net/papers/Heston-original.pdf

Comment: You mean the maths is too hard? There're lots of books that covers the same topic.

Comment: I was just hoping there might be an easier way of explaining it, could you list some of those books?

Comment: There are two steps here: (1) derivation of the c.f. for the log-price, and (2) inversion of the c.f. to recover the option price. Which step is troubling you?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot guarantee that it is error-free, but this [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2527818) (appendix A) has a relatively straightforward derivation of the Heston price for a european call.

Answer (score 1):

I try to give what I at any rate think is a clear explanation of the Fourier transform approach to option pricing for various models including Heston in More Mathematical Finance.

You could also try Lewis's book Option Valuation Under Stochastic Volatility.

Comment: I think there is a word missing somewhere in your answer...

Comment: Mark refer to section 17.9 in his book.